# Server Error in Python/Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to define a class that will allow a user to search songs, add/update and delete songs with the search returning data based on what I search (title, artist, id)

The Class:

```
from django.db import models

# music search
class musiccore(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    genre = models.TextField(max_length=40)
```

This is my URL string to return songs in browser via ID inside the actual app:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^(?p<musiccore_id>\d+)/$','musiccore.views.musiccore'),
```

This is my other Url folder:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', 'Music.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^musiccore/', include(musiccore.urls')),
```

views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def musiccore(request, musiccore_id):
    return render, (request, 'musiccore/musiccore.html')
```

I am getting a server error please contact the administrator error. 
I think his is a class problem but not sure how to resolve.
Please help!

Comment: Please enable logging in `settings.py`.So that you can find error.

Comment: Set `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py` and also post the contents of `musiccore` view in your `views.py`.

Comment: please use CamelCase names for classes in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in your view. You should rewrite the line as:

```
return render(request, 'musiccore/musiccore.html')
```

However this will only return a static page (musiccore.html), you are not actually fetching the object with `id=musiccore_id` from the database.